# Use android RootTools library to gain permission android.permission.STATUS_BAR

Tags: android, permissions, system, root, statusbar

I am trying to code an app that calls a method in android StatusBarManager. I did it the same way as the hack to expand the android status bar:

```
    try {
        Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("disable", new Class[] { int.class });
        expand.invoke(service, 0x00200000);
    } catch (Exception e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("DISABLE HOME ERROR");
    }
```

Except the method I want to call is disable() instead of expand(). 
However, I am getting a security exception "neither and user nor the current process has permission android.permission.STATUS_BAR.

I tried adding it to the manifest but because it is a system apps permission, it only works if I copy my app to /system/app.

I messed around with RootTools http://code.google.com/p/roottools/ but couldn't figure out how to set the permissions. I tried setPermissions(0) and setUserPermissions("android.permissions.status_bar") but none works. I am not really sure how to use this library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!